# HtmlHelper for custom date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Trying to use a custom HtmlHelper to output a DateTime such that it returns "Today at XX:YY", "Yesterday at XX:YY", or "Date at Time" (exact format doesn't matter at this stage - just need it to return a string).

Obviously I'm missing something vital and fundamental and ought to know better!

My helper:

```
        public static MvcHtmlString RecentDate<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

        if (metadata.Model != null && metadata.Model as DateTime? != null)
        {
            DateTime dt = (DateTime)metadata.Model;
            if (dt.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
            {
                return MvcHtmlString.Create("Today " + dt.ToShortTimeString());
            }
            else if (dt.Date == DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date)
            {
                return MvcHtmlString.Create("Yesterday " + dt.ToShortTimeString());
            }
            else
            {
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(dt.ToShortDateString() + " at " + dt.ToShortTimeString());
            }
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create("Never");
    }
```

The cshtml:

```
@model xxx.Models.ForumLatestPosts
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Latest Posts";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

<div>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>Latest Posts</dt>
        <dd>
            <table>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Threads)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Thread", new { id = item.Id })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.Title
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RecentDate(item.LastPostDate);
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

The error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0411: The type arguments for method 'xxx.HtmlHelpers.RecentDate<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Source Error:


Line 22:                         </td>
Line 23:                         <td>
**Line 24:                             @Html.RecentDate(item.LastPostDate);**
Line 25:                         </td>
Line 26:                     </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method-decleration wants a function as parameter, but you give it a property.

You could try for instead of foreach and use:

@Html.RecentDate(m =>m[i].LadtPostDate)

By the way: you could also use a custom display template.

```
@model DateTime

... Logic for displaying your date ...
```

Then the view would be something like that:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.LastPostDate, "NameOfTheEditorTemplate")
```

Comment: I had just discovered the answer (hours last night and this morning, and only just found it!). I think you're right, though the solution that worked for me was @Html.RecentDate(m => item.LastPostDate); Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the edited post. And for the helper you may use something with For at the to keep NamingConventions.